# JSON String to Array to Cache - Improve Efficiency

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script

I have cried blood finally getting this script to work (new to the google apps scripting and json, relatively familiar with javascript). It works great with a small data set, but as soon as I jump to the large, 20,000 item data set, then it times out! I can't think of another way to make this more efficient. These prices update every 3 minutes so I want to cache it for 10 minutes only. I feel like ScriptDb is not appropriate for this. Essentially I had to store information in the cache since I had ~500 equations using a simple, non-cache version of `testing()` and google/api didn't allow that many calls. I figured one call, and ~500 pulls from the cache would be better. Is there some way to make it more efficient that I am not thinking of?

This is run every 10 minutes to store the information. This piece times out.

```
function updateCache() {
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
    var myUrl = "http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/all-items/all"
    var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myUrl);
    var jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonData).results;
      for (var i =0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
      cache.put(jsonArray[i].data_id + 'sell', jsonArray[i].min_sale_unit_price, 1500);
      }
    return cache.get(itemID + 'sell')
    }
```

This is the function that uses the cache and returns the data.

```
function testing(itemID) {
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
return cache.get(itemID + 'sell')
}
```

*Update*
I updated the code to use paging. See the continued issue in Jon's comment.

```
//these are all four of the selling functions, cache for 35 min, run every 30 min
function updateSellCacheQ1() {
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
   for (var page = 0; page < 56; page++) {
   Logger.log('Sell Page #' + page);
   var myUrl = 'http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/items/all/' + page
    var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myUrl);
    var jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonData).results;
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
      cache.put(jsonArray[i].data_id + 'sell', jsonArray[i].min_sale_unit_price, 2100);
      }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have one routine (10 minute timer) that downloads the data and dumps it as a flat text file in Google Drive.

A second timer function (every 2mins say, or whatever doesn't trip the single execution fail) could then process chunks of that flat file into cache/scriptDb

so if you have a 2minute timer caching 20% of the flat file, any entry on recall will be a maximum of 13 minutes stale and a minimum of 2 minutes.

---

alternatively, could you not query the api based on the items list? so query and cache smaller chunks at a time more frequently? each query on the timer could be sequential or a random selection of the available item categories?

**update**

https://github.com/rubensayshi/gw2spidy/wiki/API-v0.9#wiki-item-list

so if you use the /items/all/{page} option in the query, you can work out how many queries you can safely make, retrieve and store in one execution. lets say it is 10.

```
var lastPageChecked = ScriptProperties.getProperty('lastPage') + 1,
    checkEnd = lastPageChecked + 10,
    myUrl,
    jsonData,
    jsonArray,
    page;

for (page = lastPageChecked; page < checkEnd; page += 1) {

  myUrl = "http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/items/all/" + page;
  jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myUrl);
  jsonArray = Utilities.jsonParse(jsonData);

  if (page <= json.last_page) {

    // [snip] process however you like

  } else {
    page = 0;
    break;
  }
}

ScriptProperties.setProperty('last_page_checked', page);
```

run that function as often as you like every query formatted in that way is cached by the api for 15 minutes, so you have 15 minutes to make the remaining 20 page calls. obviously if you can make 20 calls in one execution (2000 objects) then you only need to run the script 10 times - one every minute and you have time to spare :D

warning - i've written that in stackoverflow's editor and not tested it.

obviously if you run:

```
"http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/items/0/" + page
```

all armor, say and the same for each type you'd be running a lot more triggers, but every category might in theory be more 'current'

Comment: Unfortunately, it is hard to break up the chunks. One of the chunks of data is 10,000 items large. Do you have an opinion regarding using the cache or the scriptDb?

Comment: just checked - yup there's a lot of items :D   but the api allows for paging, so that could help also no?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what paging is. To google! I am accessing the API for like 22k items and using the data in about ~500 separate formulas. I suspect that will grow as we find more uses. I totally understand why I am hitting limits with those numbers, haha.

Comment: Here is a link to the API if that will help at all. https://github.com/rubensayshi/gw2spidy/wiki/API-v0.9

Comment: i've amended my answer to explain paging

Comment: So I ended up doing a little simpler version and just doing 55 pages per script and having four scripts run on a 10 min trigger. My previous code would finish about 7k entries so I figured 5,500 entries per script would run fine. It works fine stand alone, but all of them running every ten minutes trips the "this script is using too many computer resources" error. I have bumped it to run every 30 minutes; we shall see.

Comment: Also, I am using the "testing()" script around ~500 times and I am getting "Script invoked too many times per second for this Google user account." This is a pain!